# debugging a simulated processor

Tags: debugging

I have an embedded project which runs on a 68332 processor target (68k family).  There is no OS on the target.  We have a custom simulator that will allow our code to execute within Windows. The simulator is completely without our control to modify.  Basically the simulator is executing the machine code which isn't very good when you need to debug.  What I would really like to do is interface a debugger to allow us to debug at the source level rather than at the machine/assembly level.  Has anyone ever done such a thing?  Is there a spec that debuggers support?  Perhaps would something like gdb work for this?  Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: What kind of interfaces does the simulator have? If it doesn't already have some entry points to inspect its state and you have no control over its source, you probably can't do much. How do you execute your code? I assume you use some platform-specific compiler that outputs assembly code - is there debug information available for the executable?

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  We develop the simulator in house so we have complete control over it.  It is a MS Visual Studio c++ program.  As for the embedded 68k code, the compiler outputs an ELF, IEEE, and SREC file.  The simulator reads the SREC which simply has the binary for memory and starts executing machine instructions.  Within the simulator we have the ability to run, stop, execute etc.  The main problem is that it is not smart enough to correlate the machine instruction to the original source code.

Comment: You wrote _The simulator is completely without our control to modify._ in the question. So can you or can you not modify the simulator? If you can, you just need to pick a debugger (like gdb) and implement whatever hooks it needs to debug your programs. You need to generate debug information for your 68k programs so your simulator can link up assembly instructions with source lines.

Comment: Thanks xxbbcc.  .You are eluding to exactly what I was wondering regarding gdb.  I've been looking at the documentation and havent come across info on the hooks needed.  I would greatly appreciate if you could point me in the right direction.  Thanks

Comment: I'm sorry, I can't, I'm not familiar with gdb. It's documentation (or forums) should have information on how to provide debugging information but you'll have to track that down. Look into file formats like PDB, etc. to see what kind of debugging information you'll need to generate.

Comment: FYI, in the gdb documentation it states that gdb only supports Ada language programs produced with the GNU toolset GNAT.  We use the Adaworld compiler so I dont think this is going to happen for us.  Bummer.

Answer (score 0):

This is not necessarily an answer to your question - I'm not familiar with hooking up an existing 3rd-party debugger to a program executing inside a VM so I can't advise about that.

However, you control the source of your simulator so you can try implementing an interface (maybe a local socket, etc.) where your simulator keeps reporting status information about the code that's executing and links it up with source files by reading debug information from some generated debugging database. You'd likely have to support reading the debugging format of the compiler that compiles your 68k code and then use that information to link back assembly instructions to source code lines.

This way you're effectively implementing a debugger, but since you already have the simulator (a VM really), that's probably not too much of extra work - the simulator already has all state information about the executing 68k code, you just need a way to temporarily pause execution and extract state information during pause. Stepping through code after that is probably a trivial repeat of these steps.